# Unable to click OK button in pop-up in webdriver using ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

Unable to click on OK button
I tried like this but it is not clicking.

```
b.find_element(name: "OK").click  #----> it is not clicking
```

How to interact with this type of pop-us in ruby.

```
   <input class="copybutton" type="button" title="Copy" onclick="copyErrText()" name="copy" value=""/>
    <!-- *** Added: copy button *** -->
    <button class="button" onclick="disp()" name="OK" value="OK" type="button">OK</button>
```

Comment: You can try with action class or javascript executor

Comment: what do you mean by not clicking. are you sure there is only one button with name ok?

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the following it may help you.

```
ele = find_element(name: "OK")
driver.action.move_to(ele).click(ele).perform
```

or

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",ele)
```

or

```
driver.execute_script("disp();")
```

Comment: Murthi: I tried your code but getting this error.                                                                    ele = find_element(name: "OK")
driver.action.move_to(ele).click(ele).perform                                                                                                #-------->"Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"OK"}"

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this Watir, but your syntax is Selenium. If you are using Watir, it would look like this:

```
browser.button(name: 'OK').click
```

If there are funky javascript things going on, you can fire an event to interact with it. Use this power sparingly.

```
browser.button(name: 'OK').fire_event :click
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps.

```
 driver.switch_to.alert.accept
```

Comment: You should describe how this could help, what this solve?